# How to see deleted comments in a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-comments

Is there a way for a Facebook group moderator/admin to see deleted comments or deleted posts?

Answer (score 0):

If an administrator deleted a comment or post in a group, the comment and post are preserved for viewing and can be restored via the ["admin activity log."](https://www.facebook.com/help/151703058802391)

If a user deletes their own comment, as @serenesat pointed out, [the post or comment is deleted permanently and is no longer visible by anyone including the user who deleted it](https://www.facebook.com/help/356107851084108/?ref=u2u). If the comment had replies after it, those replies are preserved and Facebook indicates these comments were in reply to a now-deleted comment.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**No**, once a post or comment deleted means it has gone. It does not matter if it was deleted by any admin or member who had posted. No one can see that. It also will removed from Activity Log.

Comment: This is no longer correct in August 2021. Comments and posts deleted by admins are preserved and logged in the group's administrator activity logs visible only by moderators and admins.

Comment: @glenviewjeff would be good if you can add any official link or screenshot to support your comment.
I see [Facebook help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/356107851084108/?ref=u2u) still says same thing as my answer.

Comment: see my answer, screenshot included as suggested.